# OpenCV undefined reference to Mat

Tags: c++, c, windows, opencv

i'm trying to learn openCV in C++ and i'm working on codeblocks 13.12 with the latest version of openCV on Windows 7(x64). As a beginning i tested a simple output of my webcam, witch worked without troubles. Next, i tried to make modify the output with `cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY)`. As you can see below i'm getting 2 error messages. Also to clarify, `VisuWork vW` is a class that i made in order to code properly in `OOP` as exercise. The class is not doing anything special.
Please can anyone help me to find an issue to this problem?
Tks for your help and time.

---

### main.cpp :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

    class VisuWork
    {
        CvCapture* capture;
    public:
        VisuWork()
        {
            capture=cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
        };
        template<typename Type> void sHow(Type frame)
        {
    //        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); //Create image frames from capture
            cvShowImage("Camera_Output", frame); //Show image frames on created window
        }
    //    void imHSV(IplImage* frame){
    //        Mat im(frame);
    //        Mat hsv;
    //        cvtColor(im, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    //    }
        ~VisuWork()
        {
            cvReleaseCapture(&capture); //Release capture.
            cvDestroyWindow("Camera_Output"); //Destroy Window
        }

    };

        int main( int argc, const char** argv )
        {
            CvCapture* capture = 0;
            capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
            if (!capture)
            {
                // print error, quit application
            }
            else
            {
                VisuWork vW;
                while(1)  //Create infinte loop for live streaming
                {
                    IplImage* im = cvQueryFrame(capture);
                    if(!im){}
                    else{
                    //        vW.imHSV(frame);

                    Mat img_gray(im);
                    vW.sHow(im);
                  cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                    }
                    int key = cvWaitKey(10); //Capture Keyboard stroke
                    if (char(key) == 27)
                    {
                        break; //If you hit ESC key loop will break.
                    }
                }
                cvReleaseCapture(&capture); //Release capture.
                cvDestroyWindow("Camera_Output"); //Destroy Window
            }

        }
```

---

### The error messages:

***`C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.o:tried.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to cv::Mat::Mat(_IplImage const*, bool)
C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.o:tried.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to cv::fastFree(void*)`***

---

### This is the complete build log:

---

> mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -IC:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\include -c C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.cpp -o C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib" -LC:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\sources\3rdparty -o C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.exe C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.o   C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_contrib248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_contrib248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_core248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_core248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_flann248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_flann248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_gpu248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_gpu248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_legacy248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_legacy248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_ml248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_ml248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_nonfree248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_nonfree248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_objdetect248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_objdetect248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_ocl248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_ocl248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_photo248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_photo248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_stitching248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_stitching248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_superres248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_superres248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_ts248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_ts248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_video248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_video248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_videostab248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib\opencv_videostab248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_contrib248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_contrib248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_core248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_core248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_flann248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_flann248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_gpu248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_gpu248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_legacy248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_legacy248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ml248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ml248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_nonfree248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_nonfree248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_objdetect248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_objdetect248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ocl248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ocl248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_photo248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_photo248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_stitching248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_stitching248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_superres248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_superres248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ts248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ts248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_video248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_video248d.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_videostab248.lib C:\RPS\python\edp32\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_videostab248d.lib
>   ***C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.o:tried.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(_IplImage const*, bool)'
>   C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.o:tried.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to`cv::fastFree(void*)'***
>   c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PTOSH\Documents\tried.o: bad reloc address 0x2d in section `.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]'
>   c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
>   2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))

Comment: "i'm trying to learn openCV in C++" - but you're using the c-api (which is a bad idea)

Comment: Is it a good idea to mix C API inside a _class?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to use the c++ api (and you should, since the old c-one is *dead*),

```
CvCapture* capture; 
// no, use: cv::VideoCapture

IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); 
// no, use: cv::Mat frame; capture.read(frame)
```

etc. throw out all cv* functions and replace them with their cv:: counterparts
(maybe better to start again from scratch)

(btw, code snippets from SO are almost always outdated, be wary of that)

and read the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/)  (tutorial links at the bottom)

---

the whole camera-capture boils down to very few lines in c++:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // get first cam
    while( cap.isOpened() )
    {
        Mat frame;
        if ( ! cap.read(frame) ) // cam might need some warmup
            continue;

        // your processing goes here

        imshow("lalala",frame);
        if ( waitKey(10)==27 )
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```